# Civic High Mount Brake Light works only in the cold

Tags: honda, civic, brake-light

I have a '07 Honda Civic EX coupe. My high mount brake light only works when its cold outside (i.e. 40s or below) and won't work when its warmer out. The other brake lights work without any problems. I was wondering if someone could explain to me where to look to fix this problem (i.e. is the wiring default in the back panel or with the brake). I am not an expert by any means with wiring or cars. However, the dealer is asking for $389 dollars to replace the LED.

I don't think there is anything wrong with the LED though as it clearly still works.

Answer (score 1):

There have been cases on the LED's PCB loosing continuity. With the brake lamp removed and re-connected, with the ignition on and brake pedal pressed, try wiggling the LED's and connections to see if it will light up.

Changes in temperature will cause the lamp assembly to expand and contract ever so slightly and show up as working and not working as you describe.

Check wire at connector to the lamp. Ignition on 0v, but 12V with brake pedal pressed. If voltage OK then:

Remove rear deck. Remove light assembly from deck.
Two wires are soldered to its PCB board + and -. Next to + wire there is another solder connection marked +.
Solder wire + and board + together ,make the two solder blobs as one.

Reconnect the lamp and try it out for correct operation. If it all works OK now, then it is job done. Otherwise the disconnection is deeper in the lamp and is inaccessable. This will mean a new lamp.

Comment: Yup, definitely a bad connection somewhere if it is temperature sensitive.